# Variable set of attributes $facets MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, facet, faceted-search

How to use the $facet aggregation when I don't know upfront the name of all the attributes?

The documentation in https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/facet only provides examples for a fixed and known upfront set of attributes.

Comment: Check this example for reference
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428989/facet-search-using-mongodb

Comment: I did, but this example only covers the scenario of a fixed set of tags (color, size and brand)

Comment: OK. i will send a query..

Comment: How about building the query dynamically using your programming?

Comment: @styvane would be nice, if I knew which the tags are before querying. The thing is that I don't, so I need to discover them during the query

Comment: Found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75064835/perform-search-with-facets-unknown-upfront-atlas-mongodb/75073847#75073847